# Why does StreamReader.ReadLine() return a value for a one line file with no newline?

Tags: c#, readline, streamwriter

I want to append two text files together.

I have one file with a carriage return line feed at the end.  Observe file A which is 28 bytes.

> this is a line in the file\n

then I have another file which is the same thing without the new line.  Observe file B which is 26 bytes.

> this is a line in the file

I want to append the same file to itself (file A to A, and file B to B) and compare the byte counts.

However, when using `StreamReader.ReadLine()` on file A, I get a value returned but MSDN says:

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r") or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached.

However, there is no crlf in the file.

How can I safely append these files without adding an extra line break at the end?  For example, `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` will put an extra line break on file A when I don't want it to.  What would be an ideal approach?

Comment: If you just want to append the entire file, why are you concerning yourself with such invented constructs as "lines" in the first place? Either use `ReadToEnd` to get the whole thing, or read the file one block at a time. No reason to treat a couple of characters specially when you're just going to write them back verbatim anyway.

Comment: I was concerned about memory usage for larger files.  But processing the file in chunks makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StreamReader and StreamWriter (which derive from TextReader and TextWriter) are not suitable for situations requiring an exact form of binary data. They are high level abstractions of a file which consists of bytes, not text or lines. In fact, not only could you wind up with different number of newlines, but depending on the environment you might write out a line terminator other than the expected CR/LF.

You should instead just copy from one stream to another. This is quite easy actually.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathIn);
var stream = File.Open(pathOut, FileMode.Append);
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Close();
```

If the size of the file is potentially large, you should open both the input and output file at the same time and use a fixed-sized buffer to copy a block at a time.

```
using (var streamIn = File.Open(pathIn, FileMode.Read))
using (var streamOut = File.Open(pathOut, FileMode.Append)) {

    var bytes = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];

    int count;
    while ((count=streamIn.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0) {
        streamOut.Write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

}
```

Also worth noting is that the above code could be replaced by [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783870.aspx) which is new in .NET 4.

Answer (score 3):

You'll only get `null` if you call `ReadLine` *at the end of the stream*. Otherwise, you'll get all data up until *either* a `CRLF` *or* the end of the stream.

If you're trying to do a byte-for-byte duplication (and comparison), you're better off reading either characters (using `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` as you're using now) or bytes (using just using the `Stream` class) using the normal `Read` and `Write` functions rather than `ReadLine` and `WriteLine`.

You could also just read the entire contents of the file using `ReadToEnd` then write it by calling `Write` (not `WriteLine`), though this isn't practical if the file is large.

```
string data;

using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    writer.Write(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use StreamWriter.Write instead of WriteLine to avoid the extra crlf.

As to the ReadLine docs, I beleive the problem is a poorly worded explanation. You certainly wouldn't want the last bytes of a file discarded just because there is no formal line ending flag.

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on the reasons for your implementation (Why are you reading it by line and writing it back line by line?)  You could just use [`StreamWriter.Write(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx) and output all the text you have stored, the [`WriteLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx) methods are named as such because they append a newline.

> **TextWriter.WriteLine Method (String)**
>   Writes a string followed by a line terminator to the text stream.